# passport.js skipped strategy at my express application

Tags: javascript, passport.js

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

//models
require('./models/Article.model') //require model here
require('./models/About.model')
require('./models/Category.model')
require('./models/Tool.model')
var index = require('./routes/index');
var about = require('./routes/about');
var articles = require('./routes/articles');
var categories = require('./routes/categories');
var tools = require('./routes/tools');
//models

//passport-authentication
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var authenticate=require('./routes/authenticate')(passport)
//end passport-authentication

var app = express()
 var db='mongodb://localhost/myblog'
mongoose.connect(db)


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(session({secret:'http://localhost:3000/',cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//authenticate
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash())

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use('/', index);
app.use('/auth', authenticate);
app.use('/about', about);
app.use('/articles', articles);
app.use('/categories', categories);
app.use('/tools', tools);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(
    function (email, password, done) {
        debugger
        var user = {
            id: '1',
            email: 'this@email.com',
            password: '123456'
        }; // 可以配置通过数据库方式读取登陆账号

        console.log("authenticating.......")
        console.log(email);
        console.log(password)
        if (email !== user.email) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });
        }
        if (password !== user.password) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }

        return done(null, user);
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {//保存user对象
    done(null, user);//可以通过数据库方式操作
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {//删除user对象
    done(null, user);//可以通过数据库方式操作
});
// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

And here is my authenticate.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(passport){

    //sends successful login state back to angular
    router.get('/success', function(req, res){
        res.send({state: 'success', user: req.user ? req.user : null});
    });

    //sends failure login state back to angular
    router.get('/failure', function(req, res){
        res.send({state: 'failure', user: null, message: "Invalid username or password"});
    });

    //log in
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/auth/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
    }));

    //log out
    router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    return router;

}
```

And even i input the correct email and password to login, i always get below at 
console of Chrome. You can see below i print out the correct email and password.

```
opening pop up
myBlogApp.js:63 {"email":"this@email.com","password":"123456"}
myBlogApp.js:69 Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: Objectdata: Objectmessage: "Invalid username or password"state: "failure"user: null__proto__: Objectheaders: (name)status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
```

I have no idea why it's skipped the strategy because i set some console.log in strategy but it seemed not run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `passport-local` checks the request for `username` and `password` fields; if one of those isn't available, the verification callback won't be called.

You're using `email` and `password`, so you should override the default (specifically `usernameField`), like so:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // ...
  }
));
```

Documented [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#parameters).

Comment: Thank you. Last night i tried with username and password, it worked !